# Brand new galaxy tab 2 7.0 can't connect to wifi? Authentication error every time I try

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab

My tablet won't connect to wifi. I get authentication error every time
I try and it just says error every time..

Comment: Welcome to android Enthusiasts. The more information you provide, the more likely someone will be able to help you. Information like the type of router you are connecting to, the security type of the wifi password, if you are able to connect with other devices.